# How to set report page size?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

Maybe it is a newbie question, but I don't know how and where to set page size?

What is the difference between Generated Design and AutoDesignSpecs?

Why do I find the same object (label, text box etc) under either sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set your page size right-click the design node of your report, then choose "printer setup" to select the printer and "page setup" to choose paper and orientation.

By [googling around](http://objectmix.com/axapta/788204-difference-between-autodesignspecs-generateddesign-reports.html):

> With the AutoDesignSpecs you give AX metadata of what you want to put
>   in the report, and AX renders this a runtime to get the layout. This
>   is a very flexible way to declare a report and should be used for most
>   regular reports.
>
> With the GeneratedDesign you create the layout and control where to
>   put everything. This is something you'd need for documents like an
>   invoice or a packing slip.

You find the same object names in both because the generated design was initially created from the  auto design yielding the same node names.

Also see [Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa865736.aspx).